# How to implement Nested Class Constructor in Source file

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have a nested class called cell in my main class something.
I c

```
class Something{
  class Cell
    {
    public:
        int get_row_Number();
        void set_row_Number(int set);

        char get_position_Letter();
        static void set_position_Letter(char set);

        void set_whohasit(char set);
        char get_whohasit();

        Cell(int row,char letter,char whohasit);

    private:
        char position_Letter;
        int row_Number;
        char whohasit;
    };
};
```

I wanna implement nested class constructor in .cpp file

```
Something::Cell Cell(int row,char letter,char whohasit){
    Something::Cell::set_position_Letter(letter);
    Something::Cell::set_row_Number(row);
    Something::Cell::set_whohasit(whohasit);
}
```

But it is wrong. I assumed correct would be Something::Cell::Something::Cell at first but i don't think thats true either.

Comment: `Something::Cell Cell(int row, ...)` -> `Something::Cell::Cell(int row, ...)`..    Without being in `Something`, `Cell`s constructor would be `Cell::Cell`.  In the namespace, ust prefix all that with a single `Something::`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are *almost* there.  It's as simple as:

```
Something::Cell::Cell(int row,char letter,char whohasit){
    Something::Cell::set_position_Letter(letter);
    Something::Cell::set_row_Number(row);
    Something::Cell::set_whohasit(whohasit);
}
```

But actually, I would strongly recommend you use initializers, rather than constructing the members uninitialized, and then assigning to them:

```
Something::Cell::Cell(int row, char letter, char whohasit)
    :position_Letter(letter)
    ,row_Number(row)
    ,whohasit(whohasit)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your inner class public, and the method set_Position_Letter cannot be static, because `char position_Letter` is not static (here is the header):

```
class Something
{
public:
    class Cell {
    public:
        int get_row_Number();
        void set_row_Number(int set);

        char get_position_Letter();
        void set_position_Letter(char set);

        void set_whohasit(char set);
        char get_whohasit();

        Cell(int row,char letter,char whohasit);

    private:
        char position_Letter;
        int row_Number;
        char whohasit;
    };
};
```

This is the cpp:

```
Something::Cell::Cell(int row, char letter, char whohasit) {
    set_position_Letter(letter);
    set_row_Number(row);
    set_whohasit(whohasit);
}

void Something::Cell::set_position_Letter(char set) {
    this->position_Letter = set;
}

void Something::Cell::set_whohasit(char set) {
    this->whohasit = set;
}

void Something::Cell::set_row_Number(int set) {
    this->row_Number = set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my inner class has to be private for some reasons i wont detail on.